# Python: How do I make two time arrays with different units comparable?

Tags: python, time

I have the following problem:

I have one time array with "*Hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0*" as unit 
and I want to compare it with a time array with "*Seconds since midnight 2016-10-01 00:00:0.0*" as unit. Is there a python function which makes both time arrays comparable?

The motivation behind this task is to compare atmospheric variables derived from aircraft measurements with those from ERA5 reanalysis.

Thanks!

Comment: what have you done so far, can you provide your code?

Comment: How should they be compared?

Comment: Please give a better example of your input and output data. Best would be a Python data structure as code. Also please explain what "time arrays comparable" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform both to appropriate `datetime` instances, using your base date and adding the according deltas:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a1 = [datetime(1900, 1, 1)) + timedelta(hours=float(t1)) for t1 in time_array_1]
a2 = [datetime(2016, 10, 1)) + timedelta(seconds=float(t2)) for t2 in time_array_2]
```

The resulting `datetime` objects are easily comparable via `<`, `>`, etc. and you can get their difference as `timedelta` objects using the normal subtraction operator `-`.